# Keyboard notification not called with small keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, notifications, keyboard

In my code the notifications, that the keyboard will open/close are called normally when the keyboard is big. But as soon as is make it small, squishing the keyboard between to fingers, those notifications are not called anymore. Anybody having similar issues?

That is how I observe the notifications:

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillBeShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The keyboard by default reduces the size of the screen, so you have to squeeze items to make them fit.

But when you "squeeze the keyboard between your fingers", it starts to float over your views, so squeezing is no longer needed.

You can use the `UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` to get keyboard appearances info like this:

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let keyboardFrameEndRect = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect,
        let animationCurveOption = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? Int
    else { return }
    print(keyboardFrameEndRect, animationCurveOption)
    if keyboardFrameEndRect.isEmpty || // Floating keyboard is HIDING or BEING DRAGGED by the user
        keyboardFrameEndRect.origin.y >= UIScreen.main.bounds.height // Split keyboard is moving off screen
    {
        // When animation curve is zero, the keyboard is being hidden. (Otherwise, it's being moved)
        if animationCurveOption != 0 {
            print("KEYBOARD IS HIDING")
        } else {
            // e.g. ignore
            print("FLOATING KEYBOARD IS MOVING")
        }
    } else {
        print("KEYBOARD IS SHOWING")
    }
}
```

p.s. `UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` is following the current swift syntax instead of `NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame`

Answer (score 0):

You should also register `UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` (A user info key to retrieve the keyboard's frame at the end of its animation.) to observe keyboard frame changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)

@objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)
     
    //You will get notifications event here
    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
    
    } else {
   
    }
}
```

The adjustForKeyboard() method has quite a bit of work to do. First, it will receive a parameter that is of type Notification. This will include the name of the notification as well as a Dictionary containing notification-specific information called userInfo.

When working with keyboards, the dictionary will contain a key called UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey telling us the frame of the keyboard after it has finished animating. This will be of type NSValue, which in turn is of type CGRect. The CGRect struct holds both a CGPoint and a CGSize, so it can be used to describe a rectangle.